# Cloudify 2.7 and source code

Tags: cloudify

I try to download and analyze code of Cloudify 2.7 on github.
But I cannot found the web UI interface.

Where I can download the source code of web managment interface?

Thanks.

Salvo.

Answer (score 0):

The Cloudify 2.X web UI is not open source, so you will not find the source code available online.

Cloudify 2 has reached End-of-Life. You should have a look at Cloudify 3.

Barak

Comment: Ok, I know it. But if Cloudify 2.X is in EOL you think it's impossible to have the code of UI ?

Comment: Hi Salvo, suggest you send an inquiry to hello at getcloudify dot org about it